# Where can I configure iot_consensus_throttle_threshold_in_byte in IoTConsensus of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: consensus, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Where can I configure iot_consensus_throttle_threshold_in_byte in IoTConsensus of Apache IoTDB?
I met the `Reject write because there are too many requests need to process` error. This seems like the data synchronization speed between nodes in Apache IoTDB cannot keep up. Therefore, I want to adjust the synchronization parameter of IoTConsensus. I checked the official guide, and it seems to be `iot_consensus_throttle_threshold_in_byte` that needs be changed, but I wonder where is this parameter configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `iot_consensus_throttle_threshold_in_byte` is in `conf/iotdb-common.properties`path of Apache IoTDB. The default value is 50G, and you can change it to 200G and try again.